# Difference between DELETE HTTP request parameters and request body

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http

I'm trying to understand the behaviour of an HTTP DELETE request.

On my java web application, I defined the following

```
@DeleteMapping("url/route")
public ResponseEntity<String> route(@RequestParam int param1, @RequestParam long param2, @RequestParam long param3, @RequestParam String param4) {
    System.out.println(param1 + "-" + param2 + "-" + param3 + "-" + param4 );
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
    
@DeleteMapping("url/route2")
public ResponseEntity<String> route2(@RequestBody String body) {        
    System.out.println(body);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And on a java client, I do the following

```
public final void myFunction(final int param1, final long param2, final long param3, final String param4) {
    restTemplate.delete("http://localhost:8090/url/route?"
            + "param1=" + param1 + "&"
            + "param2="+ param2 + "&"
            + "param3=" + param3 + "&"
            + "param4=" + param4, String.class);
    
    restTemplate.delete("http://localhost:8090/url/route2", "SomeText", String.class);
}
```

The first request works fine, the log is well displayed. However, on the second case, i get the following error

> HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing:
> public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String>
> com.thales.atm.thmi.microservice.CanvasController.deleteGraphicObject2(java.lang.String)]

I use the module spring-boot-starter-web of spring boot (v2.7.1 on my project).

Can someone explain me what's wrong in my ussage of body parameters for this delete request ?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the restTemplate has a "delete" which takes a body, that's why the real request is failing (body is not added). I think you'll have to call pure HTTP without passing through Spring's rest template (or use the "exchange" of restTemplate where you build your own RequestHttpEntity with verb DELETE and a body)

Comment: Is there a reason you want to have a method for a DELETE request which takes a body? It's not disallowed to have a body in a DELETE request, but what it should mean is not well specified and some specifications seem to say that the body of a DELETE request should be ignored. See [Is an entity body allowed for an HTTP DELETE request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request). In other words: Don't design your REST API with a DELETE request that requires a body.

Comment: Thanks for your messages. It worked using the exchange method.
@Jesper, noted :) i didn't get this point of the spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I use the module spring-boot-starter-web of **spring boot (v2.7.1 on my
> project)**.

According to the most [recent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) version of rest template, it offers only the following `delete` methods and none of these methods expects an `entity` as parameter to be sent to `request body` of http request.

> void  delete(String url, Map<String,?> uriVariables)
>
> void  delete(String url, Object... uriVariables)
>
> void  delete(URI url)

Uri variables that the above methods offer are something different. They are passed and then used to modify the URI accordingly. If for example your URI was `./some1/some2/{foo}`, you pass a uriVariable like 2 and it makes the URI `./some1/some2/2`.

This is not what you need and you currently have no other choice, than to work around this issue, as it remains at your disposal the general `exchange` method of restTemplate.

> ```
> <T> ResponseEntity<T> exchange(String url, HttpMethod method, HttpEntity<?> requestEntity, Class<T> >  responseType, Object... uriVariables)
> ```
>
> Execute the HTTP method to the given URI template, writing the given request entity > to the request, and returns the response as ResponseEntity.

This is how it could be used.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE);

HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("SomeText", headers);
restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8090/url/route2", HttpMethod.DELETE, entity, String.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation !
I actually got confused with this put method of restTemplate :
put(String url, @Nullable Object request, Object... uriVariables)

I got confused between request & uriVariables.

It's clear, thanks :)